# Use current_timestamp +0 as variable in store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In a MySQL procedure, I want to set current_timestamp+0 to a variable and use this variable in queries.

Edited: 
I need @P_version to stay the same value during the whole procedure. I would like to get the current timestamp at the begining and use this value in all the queries.

I tried:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE P_version float;
    SET P_version = current_timestamp +0;

    insert INTO reports_4.Items(id, version, itype)
    Select I.id, P_version, I.itype from Items where I.live = 1;
    .....
END;
```

And:

```
    BEGIN
      BEGIN
        SET @P_version = 'select current_timestamp +0 from dual';
            PREPARE query from @P_version;
            EXECUTE query;
            DEALLOCATE prepare query;
        END;    
      insert INTO reports_4.Items(id, version, itype)
      Select I.id, P_version, I.itype from Items where I.live = 1;
      .....
END;
```

If I use the following, when I call my procedure a second time the value of @P_version has the same value that the first time I ran the procedure.

```
BEGIN
  select @P_version = current_timestamp +0 from dual;

  insert INTO reports_4.Items(id, version, itype)
  Select I.id, @P_version, I.itype from Items where I.live = 1;
  .....
END;
```

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set @p = now();`? mysql doesn't require selecting from dual for this sort of thing.

Comment: if I just put SET @P_version = now(); 
it says : ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'P_version' in 'field list'

Comment: it'd have to be `select i.id, @P_version, ...` later on. Vars **HAVE** to be prefaced with `@` otherwise mysql wouldn't be able to tell between what's really a var, and what's a field/table name that happens to have the same name.

Comment: Thank you it works, I do:  set `@P_version = current_timestamp +0;`  then use `@P_version` in the query

Comment: Actually it does not work as I want because `@P_version = current_timestamp +0` is changing overtime.I have a lot of query where I use `@P_version`and it's value should stay constant until the and of the procedure. I edited the question to add this requirement.

Comment: the var would only be set once for each call to the procedure. if you need it to be the same for multiple calls, then you'd have to set it somewhere outside of the procedure.